# hookActionProductUpdate called two times in module

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, smarty, prestashop

Iam creating a module for my site,Here i have used hookActionProductUpdate hook to insert some values in ps_game_key table .When product is updated insert query is executed two times.SO 2 records are inserted instead of inserting 1 record.This seems to hookActionProductUpdate is called two times.Please Help

```
 class    customsupplier
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->name = 'customsupplier';
    $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
    $this->version = '1.0';
    $this->author = 'Rex';
    $this->need_instance = 0;

    parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('Custom Supplier');
    $this->description = $this->l('Custom Supplier Module');
 }

public function install()
{
    if (!parent::install() OR
        !$this->alterTable('add') OR            
        !$this->registerHook('actionAdminControllerSetMedia') OR
        !$this->registerHook('actionProductUpdate') OR
        !$this->registerHook('displayAdminProductsExtra'))
        return false;
    return true;
}


 public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
    {


        Db::getInstance()->insert('game_key', array(
                'id_product' => 89,
                'key_type' =>'test',
                'game_key'      => 'reee',

                'added_date_time'=> 'ssd'
        ),true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook `product update` may be triggered many times, because there are a lot places where method `$product->save()` is called.

You can always prevent saving something more then once in a very simple way

```
protected $isSaved = false;

public function hookActionProductUpdate($params)
{
   if ($this->isSaved)
      return null;

   $isInsert = Db::getInstance()--insert(...);
   if ($isInsert)
      $this->isSaved = true;
}
```